# Named query not found

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In a Symfony controller, I have the following function:

```
protected function getDisplayTags(Expertise $expertise, Person $user){
    $rep = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ExpertiseDefaultBundle:Tag');

    $q = $rep->createNamedQuery('fetchTagsByExpertise'); //PROBLEM HERE

    $results = $q->setParameters(array('person'=>$user->getId()), array('expertise'=>$expertise->getId()))->getResult();
    return $results;
}
```

which throws this error: `No query found named 'fetchTagsByExpertise' on class 'Expertise\DefaultBundle\Entity\Tag'.` The repository is the generic one provided by Doctrine.

I defined the [named native query](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#named-native-query) `fetchTagsByExpertise` via annotation in the Tag entity:

```
namespace Expertise\DefaultBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="tag")
 * @ORM\NamedNativeQueries({
 *      @ORM\NamedNativeQuery(
 *          name            = "fetchTagsByExpertise",
 *          resultSetMapping= "mappingTagsByExpertise",
 *          query   ="SELECT t.id AS t_id, t.tag AS t_tag,
                    a.expertise_id AS a_expertise_id,
                        COUNT(a.person_id) AS tagcount,
                        SUM(CASE
                            WHEN a.person_id = :person THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                            END) AS has_curuser
                        FROM expertise_tags a JOIN tag t ON (a.tag_id = t.id)
                        WHERE a.expertise_id = :expertise
                        GROUP BY t.tag , a.expertise_id
                        ORDER BY t.tag"
 *      ),
 * })
 * @ORM\SqlResultSetMappings({
 *      @ORM\SqlResultSetMapping(
 *          name    = "mappingTagsByExpertise",
 *          entities= {
 *              @ORM\EntityResult(
 *                  entityClass = "__CLASS__",
 *                  fields      = {
 *                      @ORM\FieldResult(name = "id",      column="t_id"),
 *                      @ORM\FieldResult(name = "tag",     column="t_tag"),
 *                  }
 *              ),
 *              @ORM\EntityResult(
 *                  entityClass = "AssociatedTag",
 *                  fields      = {
 *                      @ORM\FieldResult(name = "expertise_id", column="a_expertise_id"),
 *                  }
 *              )
 *          },
 *          columns = {
 *              @ORM\ColumnResult("tagcount"),
 *              @ORM\ColumnResult("has_cursuser")
 *          }
 *      )
 *})
 */
class Tag
{ //vanilla Doctrine entity. NO foreign keys
  // ...
}
```

The joined entityClass, `AssociatedTag` has a composite primary key consisting of `(tag_id, expertise_id, person_id)`. I have tried including the rest of its keys in the query and mapping but it has no effect.'

Is there something wrong with how or where I've defined my named native query? Why can't the repository find it?

Comment: No sure if this is it but I see that you are doing NamedNativeQueries and creating NamedQueries

Comment: @idipous: I wondered that too. But `createNamedNativeQuery` is not a function. It throws this error: `Undefined method 'createNamedNativeQuery'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to do it is to call createNativeNamedQuery instead of createNamedQuery.

```
protected function getDisplayTags(Expertise $expertise, Person $user){
    $rep = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ExpertiseDefaultBundle:Tag');

    $q = $rep->createNativeNamedQuery('fetchTagsByExpertise'); // NO PROBLEM HERE ;)

    $results = $q->setParameters(array('person'=>$user->getId()), array('expertise'=>$expertise->getId()))->getResult();

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: I've deleted my self-answer in favour of yours.  Thanks for taking a look at an old question and giving a better answer!

Comment: Hey @dnagirl, no worries, I was facing the same issue and, since I've found the answer, I posted it here!